# No response when making POST request

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm developing a CRUD application as part of a course I am studying.

I'm able to read data from my DB, however I am now trying to add data - a new employee in this case as I am developing a company directory and so far I'm unsuccessful.

I know the issue isn't the connection with the DB as I'm able to read data. However the function getEmployeeData(); function to refresh the display of current employee records after the new addition is never called in the $.post callback func so I suspect the error happens before this point. You'll see in my code below that I'm attempting to print the firstName variable to the console. The firstName does appear in the console when the form is submitted but only for less than a second then it disappears.

I'm really stumped as to what is causing this issue.

Please see my code below:

The form in index.html:

```
<!--Form to add employee-->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Employee</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                
                <form id="addEmployeeForm" onsubmit="addEmployee()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="names">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 48% !important;" id="newFirstName" name="newFirstName" placeholder="First Name..." required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 48% !important;" id="newLastName" name="newLastName" placeholder="Last Name..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="names">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newEmail" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                  </div>
                  <div id="location-dept">
                  <select id="add-employee-dept-list" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="newDepartment">
                    <option selected>Department</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--End of add employee modal-->
```

The addEmployee() function:

```
function addEmployee() {
  let firstName = $('#newFirstName').val();
  let lastName = $('#newLastName').val();
  let email = $('#newEmail').val();
  let departmentID = $('#add-employee-dept-list').val();
  console.log(firstName);
  
  $.post(
    "php/addNewEmployee.php",
    {
      fname: firstName,
      lname: lastName,
      email: email,
      department: departmentID
    },
    function(data) {
        getEmployeeData();
        alert(data + "It worked");
    }
  )
}
```

addNewEmployee.php:

```
<?php

    // example use from browser
    // http://localhost/companydirectory/libs/php/insertDepartment.php?name=New%20Department&locationID=<id>

    // remove next two lines for production
    
    echo($_POST['$firstName']);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);
    
    // this includes the login details
    
    include("config.php");

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    $conn = new mysqli($cd_host, $cd_user, $cd_password, $cd_dbname, $cd_port, $cd_socket);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        
        $output['status']['code'] = "300";
        $output['status']['name'] = "failure";
        $output['status']['description'] = "database unavailable";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
        $output['data'] = [];

        mysqli_close($conn);

        echo json_encode($output);

        exit;

    }   

    // SQL statement accepts parameters and so is prepared to avoid SQL injection.
    // $_REQUEST used for development / debugging. Remember to change to $_POST for production

    $jobTitle = "";

    $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO personnel (firstName, lastName, jobTitle, email, departmentID) VALUES(?,?,?,?)');

    $query->bind_param("si", $_REQUEST['fname'], $_REQUEST['lname'], $jobTitle, $_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['department']);

    $query->execute();
    
    if (false === $query) {

        $output['status']['code'] = "400";
        $output['status']['name'] = "executed";
        $output['status']['description'] = "query failed";  
        $output['data'] = [];

        mysqli_close($conn);

        echo json_encode($output); 

        exit;

    }

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = [];
    
    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

Comment: One thing cought my eye is in your php you have `echo` and then `header`, the header will fail

Comment: @vaowm is right, but what do you see in the XHR console? I'd suspect your getting an error response which isnt being processed

Comment: also in your query, you have 5 columns but you're only binding to 4, and only `si` for types, learn what that means it should be `sssss`